# jQuery: modificar contenedor HTML en función del valor de la variable PHP que contiene

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

En mi web tengo una lista de 15 elementos (o conjuntos de elementos HTML) como éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El número grande y rosa lo creo a partir de una variable contador en PHP:

```
<div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span class="numero">'.$contador.'</span>'; ?> </div>
```

Querría que cada vez que la variable adquiere el valor 2 o el 12 (en general cualquiera cuyo último dígito sea un 2, pero como el máximo es 15, da igual) al contenedor `span` se le aplicase un `margin-right: 15px;` para que no quedase tan pegado al texto que lo acompaña.

He probado a hacer esto:

```
$(function()
{
    let contador = "<?php echo $contador;?>";

    if(contador == 2 || contador == 12) 
    {
        $('.numero').css('margin-right', '15px');
    }
});
```

Pero JQuery no encuentra relación entre `contador` y los objetos con `class="numero"` y se limita a añadir el estilo para todos ellos.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Se me ocurre algo así: `class="numero <php if(contador == 2 || contador == 12) echo 'numeroDos' ?>"`. Y en tu CSS `.numeroDos{margin-right: 15px}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¿Y por que no tratas el problema desde **PHP** directamente? Podrías hacer algo como esto:

**PHP**

```
<div class="mr-3"> 
<?php 
  if ($contador == 2 || $contador == 12) {
    echo '<span class="numero margen">'.$contador.'</span>'; 
  }
  else {
    echo '<span class="numero">'.$contador.'</span>';
  }
?> 
</div>
```

Añadirle o no añadirle la clase `.margen` donde esta clase tuviese:

**CSS**

```
.margen {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Otra solución, ya que parece que quieres usar Jquery para solucionarlo, sería apoyándose en un atributo `data` de **HTML5**:

```
<div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span class="numero" data-contador="' . $contador . '">'.$contador.'</span>'; ?> </div>
```

Así almacenarías `$contador` en el **HTML** y podrías cambiar el estilo de los que tengan los valores 2 o 12 unicamente:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-contador="2"]').css('margin-right', '15px');
  $('[data-contador="12"]').css('margin-right', '15px');
});
```

O ni usar **Jquery** y hacerlo directamente con **CSS**, como me sugirió el colega @x3k_js:

```
span[data-contador="2"], span[data-contador="12"] {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Realmente era por no enguarrar el código; los scripts de jQuery los tengo en otro archivo.

Comment: Edité para darte una solución "más limpia" que quizás se parezca un poco más a lo que querías conseguir.

Comment: Genial, me parece una solución muy buena.